# One field (ManyToMany) in a Django ModelForm is not saving to database

Tags: python, django

My app is project management tool where users can add, edit, and view Projects. Projects have titles, summaries, and authors (users). Users have ManyToMany relationships with Projects.

Adding new Projects was working fine until I added an edit project view. I can still create a new Project or edit an existing one, and the new title and summary get saved to the database, but the selected authors do not get saved. Note that I can still go into the shell and add authors to a project manually.

Here are the **Project** and **User models**:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    bank_id = models.CharField("researcher's four-letter bank id", null=True, max_length=4, unique=True)
    #division = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=DEPARTMENTS)
    job_title = models.CharField("job title",  max_length=30, choices=JOB_TITLES)
    citations = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DEPARTMENTS, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #history = HistoricalRecords()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField('Title')
    summary = models.TextField('Summary', default=DEFAULT_TEXT)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser)
    internal_status = models.CharField('Internal Status', max_length = 20, choices = INTERNAL_STATUS,
                                       default='wip')
    external_status = models.CharField('External Status', max_length = 20, choices = EXTERNAL_STATUS,
                                       blank=True)
    mtp_goal = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = MTP_GOALS,
                                blank=True)
    topics = ArrayField(models.CharField('Topics', max_length=30), size=4, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

**views.py**

```
def add_new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save(commit=False)
            project.created_on = timezone.now()
            project.save()
            return redirect('project_profile', pk=project.pk)
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'add_new.html', {'form': form})

def edit_project(request, pk):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST, instance=project)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save(commit=False)
            project.updated_on = timezone.now()
            project.save()
            return redirect('project_profile', pk=project.pk)
    else:
        form = ProjectForm(instance=project)
    return render(request, 'edit_project.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project, MyUser

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('title', 'authors', 'summary')
```

And finally, the **add_project.html** page (please excuse the horrific html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ResearchTracker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <a href="/about">About us</a>
      <a href="/login">Login</a>
      <a href="/admin">Admin</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
      <h1>New project</h1><br>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/">Go home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you use `commit=False` in `save`, you need to explicitly call `save_m2m` to save the many to many fields.

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False).
>   When you use a simple save() on a form, all data – including
>   many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional
>   method calls. For example:

You would do

```
project.save()
project.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks a lot! BTW the second step is actually `form.save_m2m()`